# View not found when a view model is specified

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a peculiar problem with a partial view and associated view model.
This is what the relevant function in the controller looks like:

```
using MyProject.ViewModels;

[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult ShowMyView(int id)
{
  return PartialView(new MyModel() { ModelID = id });
}
```

And then I have a view model defined as follows:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
  [Bind(Exclude = "ModelID")]
  public class MyModel: IValidatableObject
  {
    public MyModel()
    {
        Count = 1;
    }

    [Required]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ModelID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, 9999)]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(
                  ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (ModelID <= 0)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Model ID missing", 
                                          new[] { "ModelID" });

        if (Count <= 0)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Count cannot be zero", 
                                          new[] { "Count" });
    }
  }
}
```

I have a view defined in Views/Shared called ShowMyView.cshtml.
The strange thing is that when I define it as

```
@inherits WebViewPage
```

it works fine (shows the view), but when I define the actual model as well

```
@inherits WebViewPage<MyProject.ViewModels.MyModel>
```

it will not show the view and give me the error that the view cannot be found (with a list of locations it looked in, including the Views/Shared/ShowMyView.cshtml path which does exist).

This seems to happen for whichever model class I use in the project. Any clues on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: is there a reason that you need to use `@inherits` directive? By default, the view will use `<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">` defined in the web.config in the Views folder

Comment: No, I have used `@model` as well. In fact, that is what I was using at the start and then I tried `@inherits` to see if that make a difference.

Comment: It turns out to be a local issue with the other MVC system we are writing this as a plugin for.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
@inherits WebViewPage<MyProject.ViewModels.MyModel>
```

with:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.MyModel
```

in the top of your `ShowMyView.cshtml` view. Normally the two should be equivalent but you never know. Also make sure that when you are rendering this child action you are passing the id parameter:

```
@Html.Action("ShowMyView", "SomeController", new { id = "123" })
```

Comment: Good calls, but I have tried using @model and that didn't make any difference. And yes, I have included the id parameter in my Html.Action call.

Comment: @TomvanEnckevort, hmm, that's weird. I am unable to reproduce your problem. Could you provide a step by step example allowing to repro?